# How to change an existing property of a MSI using MSI transformation in ORCA

Tags: windows-installer, orca, msitransform

Does anyone have experience or idea about how to create a MSI tranform using ORCA to change the product code of a MSI. I need to allow an installation package to install multiple times in a same machine. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Orca you can generate a transform like this:

- use *Transform -> New Transform* menu to start editing
- modify what you need
- use *Transform -> Generate Transform* menu to save the transform to disk
- use *Transform -> Close Transform* menu to stop editing

Please note that for multiple instances you need to change more than just the Product Code. You also need different component GUIDs and different install locations. The Product Name should also be changed.